# Python Fuzzy Wuzzy Millions Records

Tags: python, sql-server, fuzzy-search

I have a table in SQL Server with ~6 millions records. My problem is that I'm running the fuzzy wuzzy logic in Python (with the levenshtein distance) to get the ratio of strings comparison with:

```
token_sort_ratio(string1,string2)
```

This is inside a `for loop` and insert the ratio in every line in the corresponding column ("Score").

The problem is that take ~4 hours to process all the records and I want to know if it's normal or if exists any alternative that can be better (big data or something different) on processing that number of records in less time?

Note: I want to use the Fuzzy Wuzzy logic with levenshtein distance.

Note2: I don't put the code in here because it's big but the logic is:

```
for (~6 millions)
   score = token_sort_ratio
   insert value on the table
```

Comment: The loop is what is killing you here. Your insert should be set based instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: Have you tried batching? It may be worth creating a few thousand tokens at once, then inserting them all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

@Eqomatic how can I batching the for in python? 
I tried one batching solution but it takes more time...
I saw some others solutions like vectorization, List Comprehensions, map, ... Do you thing that this things can be speed up the loop?

Comment: The idea behind batching is reducing the amount of time communicating with your db. You can do this by communicating many records to be inserted at once rather than each record at a time. In terms of batching all you really need is a counter and temporary list that keep track of, say, 100 records at a time using an inner loop or list comprehension. Once you hit that 100 (or thousand, or whatever), _that's_ when you call for the database to store all of those records.